# How the exit program with error when running a script by a trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

When I run a script with a trigger (e.g a time driven trigger) I get an email if the program has a runtime error. But how I can I throw an error that will be e-mailed to me for a error I might want to know about? i.e.  I have a few places in the code I’m developing where I could see an error might occur, but I don’t know how to handle it yet. So I’d like to write:

`console.error(“an error has happened here, come and sort it out”);`

And have that email to me like a runtime error would be.

I don't get an email about any writes to console.error or if I return an error from the program on exit. At the moment my solution is to write something like:

`null.["an error message to myself"]`

But this seems very inelegant. I could write my own email function, but as Google has done so much of the work for me I feel I should be able to use the inbuilt runtime error e-mail.

Thanks Sam

Comment: Use a [throw](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

- 1 Check execution log for errors.
- 2 Use a try catch(e) with a console log or logger log in the catch statement.
- 3 You can also sign into the error panel and request an immediate email